# D365 Same Tracking Token was assigned to Email/Case in Customer Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

One customer had a problem where an incorrect email (from another customer) was assigned to a case. The incorrectly assigned email is a response to a case that was deleted. However, the current case has the same tracking token as the deleted one. It seems that the CRM system uses the same tracking token as soon as it is available again. This should not happen! Here Microsoft has a real programming error from our point of view. The only solution we see is to increase the number of numbers to the maximum so that it takes longer until all tracking tokens are used up. But in the end, you still reach the limit.

Is there another possibility or has Microsoft really made a big mistake in the way emails are allocated?

We also activated Smart Matching, but that didn't help in this case either, because the allocation was made via the Tracking Token first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the tracking token can be configured and is set to 3 digits by default. This means that as soon as 999 emails are reached, the tracking token starts again at 1, which is basically a thinking error on Microsoft's part.

[image]

If you have set "Automatic replies", these will be reached in the shortest possible time. We therefore had to increase the number to 9 digits, which is also not a 100% solution. At some point, this number of emails is also reached and then emails are again assigned to requests that do not belong together. Microsoft has to come up with another solution.